# Laravel get title from table on basis of pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables in my database name, sms_content, sms_content_categories and categories.

Table sms_content_categories contains "categories_id" and "sms_content_id". While categories contains, "id", "title". I want to get "title" from categories title on basis of "categories_id".

Basically i am using it in datatables and i getting error.
SQLSTAT[HY00]: General error: 2031 (Sql: select 'title from categories where 'id'=?)

Here is my code:

```
$categoryID = SmsContentCategories::where('sms_content_id', $smsContentID)->pluck('categories_id')->toArray();
     $categoryName = Category::where('id', $categoryID)->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

I want to get title from categories.

Comment: `dd($categoryID)` to make sure it contains what it should

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get "title" from categories title on basis of "categories_id".

Not tested but this should work:

```php
$categoryIds = SmsContentCategories::whereIn('sms_content_id', $smsContentID)->pluck('categories_id');

$categoryTitles = Category::whereIn('id', $categoryId)->pluck('title');
```

Comment: Thankyou for, response . Now i am getting dataTables ajax error. like "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"

Comment: @FaisalKhan What response do you get if you try the first line in a tinker session? `php artisan tinker`